# In a book, what are the pros and cons of short, medium-length, and long multi-clause chapter titles?

Tags: title, books, heading

Chapter titles in a book can be like this:

- Autumn
- Winter
- Looking back

or like this:

- Life in the old country
- The day of the move
- What James thought he knew

or like this:

- Between 10 and 20: from mid-childhood to the first growth pangs of real adult life
- Where there's muck, there's money: how I escaped the world of shovelling dung and became a billionaire
- My last week in prison and my first week as a project manager
- Steel yourself: how I coped with change by viewing it as continuity

What are the pros and cons for UX, in a book and especially one that's printed, of chapter titles that are short, medium-length, and long?

Comment: I don't understand your question, if the titles are those, what is the point of considering the pros and cons? At least you expect an answer as to how the design should be in this situation.

Comment: Those are hypothetical (but realistic) examples of short, medium-length, and long chapter titles. The question is about the pros and cons not of those examples but of short, medium-length, and long chapter titles more generally. I don't "expect" an answer, but I will be grateful to anyone who does answer. Answers to the more general question will be more likely to be useful to more readers of this website than answers to a highly specific question. The point of considering the pros and cons is the same as the point of considering the UX pros and cons of any other aspect of design.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a bit too broad, and I would say that the pros and cons of the length or style of chapter titles need to fit with the type of book or content that you are writing. Considering that you are focusing on printed books, I suggest that the practical purpose of chapter titles are to mark specific sections of the book, and hence it just needs to be unique and sequential in its labeling to be most useful.

If it is a non-fiction book, then readers would probably expect chapters titles that are practical for locating the information they are looking for quickly, as they are not always designed to be read from start to finish (e.g. reference books).

For fictional books, the story may be told chronologically or linearly and therefore the chapter titles again act as place holders. For stories that might not follow the traditional structures, the chapter titles might help serve as reminders to the reader of the plot.

This is a case where more is not necessarily better, and less is also not worse. It just depends on what the content is and what the best way to break it up into navigable sections.